# Logical indexing with two conditions

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a `rankingMat` which contains the rankings of equity tickers, where every column represents one ticker and every row represents a point in time. The ranking has been performed in a descending manner, i.e. a 1 in `rankingMat` identifies the highest rank for that time period (read: row). Ticker/column 4 represents a cash security. This will be important further down the road.

Now, I would like to identify in which equity tickers I am supposed to invest. There exists two conditions:

1. I only invest in tickers that have a rank less or equal to 3.
2. In addition, I only invest in tickers that are ranked higher or equal compared to cash (ticker/column 4).

---

I'm able to get a result that fulfills the first condition:

```
rankingMat = ...
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; ...
    1, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4; ...
    4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1; ...
    4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3; ...
    6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3; ...
    2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5; ...
    3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5; ...
    2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3];

portfolio = rankingMat <= 3;
```

The result looks like this:

```
portfolio = ...
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; ...
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0; ...
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1; ...
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1; ...
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1; ...
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0; ...
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0; ...
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

My problem is condition 2. In every row, I need to compare not only if the integer is less or equal to 3, I also need to make sure that it is less than the integer in column 4 in that particular row. I am looking for a solution that avoids a for-loop. I guess it is possible with indexing. So, any hint is highly appreciated.

The final result should look like this:

```
portfolio = ...
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; ...
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0; ...
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1; ...
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1; ...
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0; ...
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0; ...
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; ...
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% Prior to R2016b
portfolio = rankingMat <= 3 & ...
            bsxfun(@lt, rankingMat, rankingMat(:,4));

% On or after R2016b
portfolio = rankingMat <= 3 & ...
            rankingMat <  rankingMat(:,4);
```

Comment: ...This is quite a neat solution, especially for the 2016b version. It looks quite intuitive. One question regarding bsxfun, is this function using a loop, that is, from the perspective of execution speed, is the usage of bsxfun comparable to solve that problem using a for-loop?

Comment: `bsxfun` is a built-in function. Internally it of course does a "loop", but the MathWorks really did their best making it as fast as possible. It's multithreaded, meaning it will evaluate the comparisons on multiple cores simultaneously, whereas a simple loop in MATLAB would only ever use 1 core.

Comment: In R2016b, they finally got rid of it altogether in favor of an implementation of it at language-level. [Here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) is a bit more background.

Comment: Although mathematically incorrect (which is part of why they took so long to change it), it's exactly what Python and others were already doing for years, just because it's so damn convenient.